# What causes wind like sound in glass (or in similar object)?

Tags: acoustics

If you take drinking glass (or similar object) from rim side, very close to your ear, you can hear sound, like wind.

Don't need to  rub your finger around glass rim, or cause sound somehow,  that sound exists by itself.

Question, what causes that sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wind sound is random noise from outside the glass cup which gets trapped inside the glass cavity, where it bounces around. Since the glass does not absorb that sound, its intensity will build up slightly inside the glass as more random noise from outside comes in and starts bouncing around in there. The resulting buildup of random noise is loud enough for you to hear it.

Comment: The traditional device is a sea shell, and it is supposed to sound like the sea.

Comment: Yeah, and when I as a kid tried that trick 60 years ago I thought it didn't sound like the sea at all!